# MySql auto_increment duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, sql-insert

Mysql auto_increment works by adding 1 to the maximum value every time there is a new row, supposing 2 rows are inserted at exactly the same time in micro seconds.
Unless mysql locks a table by default while inserting, I see a possibility of duplicates, and would like to know;
Do you end up with duplicates for this case?

Comment: can post your code ?

Answer (score 3):

No, never. MySql will ensure that it will never happen.
It will do a internal lock to ensure that.

The auto_increment value will be unique in the table where it is defined.

Comment: Ok, coz the only way to avoid a duplicate in this case would be to initially lock the table in one way or another.

Comment: @ttopaul, that is correct. It the column was a normal INT value type with no extra attributes. Then yes, there should be a possibility for a update collision.